# RxJava - error handling in subjects

Tags: mvvm, error-handling, rx-java, rx-android, subject

I'm trying to implement a ViewModel in MVVM, providing observables as "input stream" and observer as "output stream" for view to bind.

The code below seems to work if getUser() call succeeds, but throws an uncaught exception if fails:

```
public class ViewModel {

    private final BehaviorSubject<String> query;
    private final BehaviorSubject<User> result;

    public ViewModel() {
        result = BehaviorSubject.create();
        query = BehaviorSubject.create();
        query.flatMap(s -> getUser(s)).subscribe(result);

        //  result = result.doOnError(e -> onError(e));    //  does not work
    }

    Observable<String> login() {
        return result.map(user -> user.getLogin());
    }

    Observable<String> blog() {
        return result.map(user -> user.getBlog());
    }

    public Observer<String> queryObserver() {
        return query;
    }

    private void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

How can I get onError() method executed in case of error, without pushing anything to login and blog observables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doOnError()` is a "side-action" operator, it doesn't catch the error. Should be something like:

`query.flatMap(s -> getUser(s)).subscribe(result::onNext, this::onError);`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but result is a subject, so subscribe() will not accept other parameters.

Comment: @ZbigniewMalinowski my bad, forgot to amend the first param. Fixed!

Comment: Ok, that will do. Thanks!